# 3 column layout with responsive central column

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to build a responsive three column layout. However, I want fixed widths on my outer columns and I want the central column to take up all the remaining space.

So if the screen was 900px wide and my outer columns were 200px and 300px respectively, the central column would take up the remaining 400px.

So far I have

```
.column-left,
.column-main,
.column-right {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;    
    height: 100%;
}
.column-left {
    width: 200px;
}
.column-main {
    width: 100%;
}
.column-right {
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
}
```

but this pushes the middle column down onto the next line and the third column is pushed down another line as well.

Comment: Post your HTML, or create a jsFIddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1: Table Layout

Why not use a CSS table layout? nb. this is valid here as a layout, as opposed to the semantic `table` element used for data content.

```css
html,
body,
.table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  background:lightgrey;
}
.cell:first-child,
.cell:last-child {
  width: 200px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="cell"></div>

</div>
```

### Option 2: Positioned Layout

Alternatively, you can position your elements...

```css
html,
body,
div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 200px;
  width: calc(100% - 400px);
  background:lightgrey;
}
div:first-of-type,
div:last-of-type {
  background: grey;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
div:first-of-type {
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
}
div:last-of-type {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**added** `float:right` to code and **removed** `width:100%` from code,it works,hope it helps,have a look at [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wv14qbt4/1/)